# how do I configure dummy interface with netplan on ubunty 17.10?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

how do I configure dummy interface with netplan?

I could manually configure them with systemd:

Configure the dummy interface to setup at boot:
        edit `/etc/systemd/network/dummy0.netdev`
        add

```
[NetDev]
Name=dummy0
Kind=dummy
```

edit `/etc/systemd/network/dummy0.network`
        add

```
[Match]
Name=dummy0

[Network]
Address=169.254.1.1/32
```

how do I get the same result with netplan?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1773997

After it is fixed you should be able to create `/etc/netplan/02-dummy.yaml` with content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  bridges:
    dummy0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      interfaces: [ ]
      addresses:
        - 169.254.1.1/32
```

And execute

```
( umask 0022; netplan apply; );
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, netplan does not support creating dummy interfaces. You should be able to create the dummy device outside of netplan and use netplan to assign an address to it.

If you think netplan should support dummy interfaces you may find this useful:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1774203

Using a bridge could potentially provide the same functionality for you but it's not the same thing as a dummy interface.